# Sorting lists by purrr::transpose but some value is missing

Tags: r, sorting, transpose, purrr

I want to sort the lists depending on the number of "a" in each element.

```
library("purrr")
data1 <- c("apple","appreciate","available","account","adapt")
data2 <- c("tab","banana","cable","tatabox","aaaaaaa")
list1 <- list(data1,data2)
ca <- lapply(list1, function(x) str_count(x, "a"))
t2 <- Map(split, list1, ca)
t3 <- transpose(t2)
> t3
$`1`
$`1`[[1]]
[1] "apple"   "account"

$`1`[[2]]
[1] "tab"   "cable"


$`2`
$`2`[[1]]
[1] "appreciate" "adapt"     

$`2`[[2]]
[1] "tatabox"


$`3`
$`3`[[1]]
[1] "available"

$`3`[[2]]
[1] "banana"
```

It lost the "aaaaaaa" which in data2. How can I fix this problem?

I had find a solution:

```
data1 <- c("apple","appreciate","available","account","adapt")
data2 <- c("tab","banana","cable","tatabox","aaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaa")
list1 <- list(data1,data2)
ca <- lapply(list1, function(x) str_count(x, "a"))
k11<- flatten(Map(split, list1, ca))
k1<-split(k11, as.integer(names(k11)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citing the words of [lionel](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/397#issuecomment-336848111): "`transpose()` treats lists of lists as implicitly rectangular tables". It was not designed for many edge cases like the current one. However, you could get the requried put by place the longer one at the begining: `transpose(t2[2:1])`.

However, this workaround could not generalize. I prefer the following way --- combine the sublists into a single list and split again:

```
> t3 <- do.call(c, t2)
> split(t3, names(t3))
$`1`
$`1`$`1`
[1] "apple"   "account"

$`1`$`1`
[1] "tab"   "cable"


$`2`
$`2`$`2`
[1] "appreciate" "adapt"     

$`2`$`2`
[1] "tatabox"


$`3`
$`3`$`3`
[1] "available"

$`3`$`3`
[1] "banana"


$`7`
$`7`$`7`
[1] "aaaaaaa"
```

---

### Edit

A function for named and unnamed input:

```
data1 <- c("apple","appreciate","available","account","adapt")
data2 <- c("tab","banana","cable","tatabox","aaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaa")
list1 <- list(data1,data2)
names(list1) <- c("atf","bdfs")

f <- function(x){
    if(is.null(names(x))){
        names(x) <- make.names(seq_along(x))
    }
    dtf <- stack(x)
    res <- split(dtf, str_count(dtf$values, 'a'))
    lapply(res, function(y) split(y$values, y$ind, drop = TRUE) )
}

f(list1)
```

Comment: Thank you @mt1022. I have checked the Q&A of lionel and found the solution. Thank you

Comment: Hi @mt1022 now I used k11<- flatten(Map(split, list1, ca)); k1<-split(k11, names(k11)) to fix my problem. But when there is a number over 10, the order of the output list will be 0,1,10,11,2,3... How can I reorder it from small to big, like 0,1,2,3,4.... Thank you

Comment: @Codezy, I guess you can do it this way: `k1 <- split(k11, as.integer(names(k11)))`

Comment: Wow, this answer works thank you so much. Could you tell me why as.integer will sort it properly?

Comment: @Codezy, `split` will do the sort based on the data type of second argument. When you split by `names(k11)`, `split` get character vector as splitting factor and sort it alphabetically. When `as.integer(names(k11))` was used, `split` got integer vector as splitting factor and will sort it numerically.

Comment: Thank you @mt1022 you are so kind. Your answer helps me a lot. Have a nice day bro

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @mt1022. I just find out if the list has a name then it would not work. Do you have any idea how to fix this problem? data1 <- c("apple","appreciate","available","account","adapt")
data2 <- c("tab","banana","cable","tatabox","aaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaa")
list1 <- list(data1,data2)
names(list1) <- c("atf","bdfs")

Comment: @Codezy, I didn't get your point. You final solution seems work with named list.

Comment: @Codezy, I added a function for both named and unnamed input.

Comment: Thank you, your answer works. I have found another solution with my real data by using sub("([[:digit:]]+)$","",data) to rename it. Then merge the one with the same name. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this using pipe with `purrr` functions

```
map(list1, str_count, "a") %>% 
        map2(list1, ., split) %>%
        flatten %>% 
        split(names(.))
#$`1`
#$`1`$`1`
#[1] "apple"   "account"

#$`1`$`1`
#[1] "tab"   "cable"


#$`2`
#$`2`$`2`
#[1] "appreciate" "adapt"     

#$`2`$`2`
#[1] "tatabox"


#$`3`
#$`3`$`3`
#[1] "available"

#$`3`$`3`
#[1] "banana"


#$`7`
#$`7`$`7`
#[1] "aaaaaaa"
```